# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 - /authorization/v1/clients/instance - 404 Not Found

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid, mobilefirst-server

I have developed a MobileFirst 7.1 Hybrid application in eclipse with ipad environment.

This ipad environment is configured with a custom security test that has the following realm:

```
<customSecurityTest name="myIpadTest">
    <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" />
    <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm"  isInternalUserID="true" />
</customSecurityTest>
```

In the application-descriptor.xml

```
<ipad bundleId="com.xxx.xxx.xxx" securityTest="myIpadTest" version="1.0">
   ....
</ipad>
```

This application when installed in the real device works properly with my  ***Eclipse environment*** and my ***Staging MobileFirst Server***.   The ***Staging MobileFirst Server*** has HTTP Server ***Nginx*** in front of it without SSL.

But when I deploy the same application in the ***Production MobileFirst Server*** the device fails to register with the below error logs. This production server has a nginx also in front of it that acts as a reverse proxy to the mobilefirst server and is configured with SSL with a valid CA Issued Certificate. TLSv1.2 with SHA256 Cipher.

```
2016-08-24 14:57:33.087 MyApp[2388:1849431] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:244 :: Sending request (https://xxx.xxx.xxx.com:443/myapp/authorization/v1/clients/instance) with headers: 
{
    "Accept-Language" = en;
    "User-Agent" = "MyApp/1.0 (iPad; iOS 9.3.2; Scale/2.00)/WLNativeAPI/7.1.0.0";
    "X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest;
    "x-wl-app-version" = "1.0";
    "x-wl-device-id" = "1293712973921739217398217893721";
    "x-wl-platform-version" = "7.1.0.0";
}
You can see the request body in the Analytics platform logs.
2016-08-24 14:57:33.094 MyApp[2388:1849431] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:356 :: Starting the request with URL https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.com:443/myapp/authorization/v1/clients/instance
2016-08-24 14:57:33.095 MyApp[2388:1849431] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] __42-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:]_block_invoke in WLRequest.m:254 :: waiting for response... (Thread=<NSThread: 0x13cd16140>{number = 1, name = main})
2016-08-24 14:57:33.096 MyApp[2388:1849431] THREAD WARNING: ['WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin'] took '86.991943' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
08-24 14:57:33.455 INFO  App           Sending no login credential event with cause 0           [ UserCredentialReportThread_0, SendNoLoginCredentialEvent, /Users/iosbuild/TAGS/TAG_VC_3_3_4_0004/Products/Client/ClientLib/AppLogic.cpp:15304 ]
2016-08-24 14:57:33.455 MyApp[2388:1849664] Received event=202002
2016-08-24 14:57:33.456 MyApp[2388:1849664] Sending Data to JS key callStatus, value 202002
2016-08-24 14:57:33.456 MyApp[2388:1849664] Unknown event 202002
2016-08-24 14:57:34.409 MyApp[2388:1849431] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:388 :: Request Failed
2016-08-24 14:57:34.412 MyApp[2388:1849431] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:389 :: Response Status Code : 404
2016-08-24 14:57:34.415 MyApp[2388:1849431] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:390 :: Response Error : Request failed: not found (404)
2016-08-24 14:57:34.420 MyApp[2388:1849431] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2016/05/13 10:26:34
2016-08-24 14:57:34.421 MyApp[2388:1849431] [ERROR] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLRequest.m:509 :: Status code='404' error='Request
```

I thought the issue was caused by the Reverse proxy so i decided to install the desktopbrowser version in the production but i dont have any 404 issues with the desktopbrowser.  The certificate is also trusted by the browser.

Looking forward for your help guys.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you removed the reverse proxy, but tested with a different app environment. Did you try testing it in iOS, without the reverse proxy?

Comment: any updates to this question?